# Change render size in DirectX11

Tags: c#, rendering, directx-11, sharpdx

Imagine that I'm working on a 1920x1080 image, doing some computations on those pixels, but I'm interested in showing to the user only a centered part of that rendered image (for example a 500x500).
There is a way to show in my window only a part of the Swapchain using its Present() function ?

Comment: Specifically, I'm using the SharpDX Swapchain1, enhanced version of the SwapChain.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem by using a second display doing off-screen rendering at a different resolution. After that rendering, it pass a texture2d to the smaller "real" display which crops it to adapt to the smaller resolution. Thanks anyway!